# What is meant by $\big[T\big]_{\mathcal B^\prime, \mathcal B}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: \textbf{V} \to \textbf{W}$ be a linear transformation, where $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B^\prime$ are bases for the $n$-dimensional space $\textbf{V}$ and the $m$-dimensional space $\textbf{W}$, respectively.

Now we often make use of the matrix representation $\big[T\big]_{\mathcal B^\prime, \mathcal B}$ of $T$ with respect to the given bases.

However, I am not completely sure what that means though? Can someone please try and explain the concept of what exactly is meant by the matrix representation $\big[T\big]_{\mathcal B^\prime, \mathcal B}$ of $T$ with respect to the given bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the first basis is $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n$, and the second basis is $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_n$. Then for each $i$, you can express $t(v_i)$ in terms of the $w_j$; $$T(v_i)=a_{i1}w_1+a_{i2}w_2+\cdots+a_{in}w_n$$ The matrix you are after is the matrix of coefficients $a_{ij}$.